# Why is this railstutorials `follow` function works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading railstutorials, and can't follow this point.

A method `follow!` in user model class calls `create` method in relationships controller class.
And the `create` method calls the `follow!` method other way around.

Why this doesn't cause a endless loop?

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end
end
```

controllers/relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

Here is a link to the tutorial : http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=2.3#code:following_p_follow_bang

Comment: Could you post a link to this code, so we can get some more context?  Thanks.

Comment: Added reference link ie Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial.

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot add the link and thanks for adding it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no loop in your example.

The `User` class (`models/user.rb`) has a one-to-many (or many-to-many) relationship with a `Relationship` model class (`models/relationship.rb`). We are here on the Model side of the MVC, totally independent of the Controller side.

The `relationships` in the ActiveRecord User class (`models/user.rb`) is absolutely not related to the `RelationshipController` class (`controllers/relationships_controller.rb`): The `relationships.create!` in the User class calls the "create" method of its nested Relationship model (`models/relationship.rb`). The `create` method in the `RelationshipController` (`controllers/relationships_controller.rb`) is just one of the several methods of the CRUD/REST architecture pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`relationships.create!` gets called on the model. The `create` method you see is defined in the relationships controller.

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
   ...
end
```

is **controller** code. It is of class `RelationshipsController`. When you call `User#relationships`, the object you are referencing is a **model**. It is of class `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and has nothing to do with the `create` method defined in the controller.

Comment: I can't get the difference the example code and what you write. Could do tell me more understandable for me?